# What is meaning of "re.compile(r'~(\w+)(?=.+[^~]\1)')" in python , specially why "\1" is being used here?

Tags: python, regex

```
string s1 = "~c0 & (a0 | b0 | z0) & (a0 | a1 | ~b0) & (b0 | b1 | ~a0) & (c1 | ~a0 | ~b0)"
p1  = re.compile(r'~(\w+)(?=.+[^~]\1)')
p2 = re.compile(r'~(\w+)(?=.+[^~]\1)')
b1 = p1.findall(s1)
b2 = p2.findall(s1)
```

As a result :

I am receiving this below:

```
['a0', 'b0', 'a0', 'a', 'b0', 'b']
['c', 'b0']
```

I am expecting :

```
['a0', 'b0', 'a0', 'a1', 'b0', 'b1']
['c1', 'b0']
```

Somehow , the 1 followed by the character are being omitted .
Can anyone help to understand why ?

Comment: `\1` is a back-reference. It matches whatever `(\w+)` matched.

Comment: I don't get that output. When I ran your code, I first had to remove `string` at the start to make it work, and then the value of `b1` was `['c', 'b0']`. Please clarify how you got `['a0', 'b0', 'a0', 'a', 'b0', 'b']` ?

Comment: `\1` is in a lookahead, so it's not included in the match.